# How to convert this rnoaa output to a data frame R

Tags: r, rnoaa

I'm using the rnoaa package for the first time. The data output is in a format I have not used before. How can I convert this to a nice dataframe that is ready to manipulate? below is the code and output

```
library("rnoaa")
ncdc(datasetid='GHCND', stationid = "GHCND:USC00182906", datatypeid='PRCP', 
startdate = '2006-01-01', enddate = '2007-01-01', limit=400, token =  
"API CODE")

$meta
$meta$totalCount
[1] 169

$meta$pageCount
[1] 400

$meta$offset
[1] 1


$data
    date                    datatype  station         value fl_m fl_q fl_so fl_t
1   2006-07-14T00:00:00     PRCP GHCND:USC00182906     5               H 0700
2   2006-07-15T00:00:00     PRCP GHCND:USC00182906     0               H 0700
3   2006-07-16T00:00:00     PRCP GHCND:USC00182906     0               H 0700
4   2006-07-17T00:00:00     PRCP GHCND:USC00182906     0               H 0700
5   2006-07-18T00:00:00     PRCP GHCND:USC00182906     0               H 0700
6   2006-07-19T00:00:00     PRCP GHCND:USC00182906   109               H 0700
7   2006-07-20T00:00:00     PRCP GHCND:USC00182906     0               H 0700
8   2006-07-21T00:00:00     PRCP GHCND:USC00182906     3               H 0700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access the `$data` portion of the results from the `ncdc()` call, it's already a `data.frame`. There is nothing further you need to do. You can save it as its own object as follows.

```
library("rnoaa")
dataset <- ncdc(datasetid='GHCND', stationid = "GHCND:USC00182906", datatypeid='PRCP', 
          startdate = '2006-01-01', enddate = '2007-01-01', limit=400, token =  
            "API CODE")
df <- dataset$data
```

To verify that it is indeed a `data.frame` you can check with:

```
> class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks for the help!